# list add error without activity in android

Tags: java, android, list, android-activity

when code run without extending activity and oncreate method invocation it give error:

```
public class RequestActivity {
//extends Activity{

//protected void onCreate(android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    // Creating HTTP client
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    // Creating HTTP Post
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
            "http://www.example.com/login");

    // Building post parameters
    // key and value pair
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    //following error in below 2 lines
    //========errors:=================
    //Multiple markers at this line
    //- Syntax error on token "add", = expected after this token
    //- Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "user@gmail.com"));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message",
            "Hi, trying Android HTTP post!"));
    //==============================================
    // Url Encoding the POST parameters
    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // writing error to Log
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Making HTTP Request
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        // writing response to log
        Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // writing exception to log
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // writing exception to log
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
}
```

when class is extended with activity and code is put inside oncreate method , it runs good. So why this is not working in previous case.

Errors are marked as comment inside code.
[image]

gist for complete code:
https://gist.github.com/prashantdawar/72f86fa497b677e1bc85

Comment: But why you run this code in `Activity`? better to create `separate class` or `AsyncTask` to run this code....

Comment: I suggest you read the Android documentation or google for an Android tutorial.

Comment: thats what happening. when creating standalone class it gives error as described in code above. @MD

Comment: creating a standalone class without activity giving error. Its about datastructure not about activity. @Code-Apprentice

Comment: What error do you get? Are we supposed to guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that when you comment out the `onCreate()` method, your code is no longer valid Java. Remember that code must go inside **some** method. It can be any name you wish, not necessarily `onCreate`.

Comment: true. but i cannot upvote you because my reputation went down below 15 due to -ve vote to post. like to upvote you.

Comment: @devprashant If this answer helped solve the problem, please accept it. You will get 2 points and be able to upvote as well.